# Как задать первые ДВА слова заголовка другим цветом в php?

Tags: php, слайдер

знатоки!

Имеется шаблон https://wordpress.org/themes/bizberg/.

В php-коде реализовано первое слово заголовка слайдера (class="firstword") другим цветом.
Однако в английском варианте "The World is beautiful" нет смысла выделять другим цветом первое слово - артикль "The", есть смысл выделить ДВА первых слова "The World".

Как это сделать? Есть идеи?
ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО!

(Код реализации "firstword" ниже)

**functions.php:**

```
return '<h1 class="slider_title_layout_' . $slider_title_layout . ' ' . $slider_text_align . '">' .  '<span class="firstword">'.$title[0].'</span>'.substr(implode(" ", $title), strlen($title[0])) . '</h1>';
```

**front-page-hero.php:**

```
array(
            'element'  => '.slider_title_layout_3 .firstword,.slider_title_layout_4 .lastword',
            'property' => 'color'
        ),
```

Comment: Глючит сайт ru.stackoverflow.com. Трижды добавил обращение "Здравствуйте, знатоки!", а редактор сайта удаляет первое слово и оставляет только "знатоки!". Печально, что такой знаменитый сайт имеет такие детские глюки...

Comment: Если сайт мультиязычный и на нем есть некие файлики с переводами, то "The World" и "is beautiful" -- просто разные фразы для перевода

Comment: @Maksym'sDesign FAQ сайта гласит о том, что содержание вопроса должно быть в рамках темы возникшей проблемы. без прелюдий.

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov Сайт мультиязычный (https://hunger-hilfe.de). Но первое слово задано в php как переменная, поэтому цвет первого слова меняется с белого на заданный цвет темы на любом языке :) Вопрос в том, как в качестве переменной задать ДВА первых слова? :)

Comment: @webDev_  Спасибо, буду знать. Просто привычка обращаться к людям вежливо :)

Comment: Это же отлично, что сайт самостоятельно удаляет всякую воду типа "здравствуйте". Не знал о таком.

Comment: Познания в php совсем нулевые, да?

Comment: Нет, я профи, здесь заблудился просто :) Шутка. Есть предложение по теме?

Comment: проследите, откуда берется $title, где он становится массивом; Откуда берется фраза "The World is beautiful"?

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov Спасибо! Я, возможно, не понял ответа. Title берется из заголовка страницы, которую я использую в качестве слайда. Фото слайда берется из изображения страницы. А если нужно проследить переменную $title, то, честно говоря, не представляю, где ее искать. В исходном коде страницы ее нет. Подскажете?
Тема вот:
https://wordpress.org/themes/bizberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не спец по wordpress и его темам, а просто девелопер, который проходил мимо.

"The World is beautiful" (title) изначально, вероятно, строка-предложение.

В `functions.php` видно: `$title` -- уже много строк-слов.

Вероятно, где-то в `???.php` (в основном коде или в теме или wordpress-е) есть код, который разделяет title на слова пробелами: `split(" ",` или `explode(" ",`.

Идея в том, чтобы заменить там разделитель с `" "` на `"^"`, а заголовки писать: "The World ^ is beautiful"

Comment: Разделитель находится здесь же, дальше в строке:

Comment: это склеиватель

Comment: ВСЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ! 
Я задал вопрос на английском форуме и получил ответ: "Replace both occurrences of $title[0] with $title[0].' '.$title[1]."  

Изменил - и все работает! Проблема теперь в том, что оно меняет цвет первых двух слов на ВСЕХ слайдах, а не только там, где артикль на первом месте... Придется либо жить с этим, либо добавлять в панель кастомизации выбор типа слайдера для каждого слайда отдельно :)

Comment: на всех языках?

Comment: К сожалению, да. Не на всех слайдах впереди стоит артикль, а на русском языке - и подавно. "Thank you" можно было бы и оставить, но все равно нужно создавать отдельный layout теперь для выделения только первого слова. Как-то сразу я не обратил внимания на то, что в панели кастомизации меняется стиль ВСЕГО слайдера, а не отдельных страниц. My bad :(

Comment: ищите разделитель; можете весь functions.php в вопрос вывалить

Comment: Не влезает код. Там больше 60000 символов. Я уже добавил в кастомизацию отдельный вид слайдера с двумя цветными словами. На русском - с одним словом, а на иностранных - пока везде два. СПАСИБО Вам, что возитесь с этим...

Comment: Попробовал написать в заголовке "The World ^ is beautiful". Значок показывается на слайдере как текст. Поэтому замена разделителя с " " на "^", видимо. не имеет смысла

Comment: Замена будет иметь смысл, когда код станет делить по "^". Eсли вы в программировании не на один раз, заведите пользователя на github. Там можно код хранить, показывать и т. п.

Comment: а explode или слова содержащие split

Comment: explode - вот я... это там же, где $title строкой выше!  
    
      case '3':
   $title = explode( " ", $title );
   return '<h1 class="slider_title_layout_' . $slider_title_layout . ' ' . $slider_text_align . '">' .  '<span class="firstword">'.$title[0].'</span>'.substr(implode(" ", $title), strlen($title[0])) . '</h1>';
   break;

Comment: ВСЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ! СПАСИБО! Я так понимаю, разделитель "^" программно php не выводит на экран.

Comment: Чтобы теперь не ставить "^" в каждом заголовке
попробуйте так: ``` $title = explode( strpos($title, "^") ? "^" : " ", $title ); ```. Если получилось "принимайте ответ" и голосуйте стрелочкой.

Comment: То есть, два пробела ставить вместо ^ в заголовке, или? Не пойму, как разделитель будет определяться браузером? Я убрал из заголовка ^ и выделяется только 1 слово снова.

Comment: `$title = explode( strpos($title, "^") ? "^" : " ", $title );` тут написано: если в заголовке есть "^", то бить по нему, если нет -- бить по " ", как раньше; режем-красим-клеим; браузер не при делах, php работает на сервере.

Comment: Урок усвоен. ОТВЕТ ПРИНЯТ! Еще раз СПАСИБО за разъяснение!